# pypyodbc crashes with 'Invalid string or buffer length' on x64

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, pypyodbc

I try to import data to my MSSQL database, however sometimes(! around 9 of 10 times) the code crashes on a Python x64 platform.

> [HY090] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length

The same code runs fine on 32-bit.

The code gets problems on running sqlGetTypeInfo with SQL_TIMESTAMP(93):

```
connection="DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s"%((db["SQL_SERVER"],db["db"],db["user"],db["pwd"]))
conn=pypyodbc.connect(connection)
cur=conn.cursor()
print cur.getTypeInfo(93)
```

I am running pypyodbc 1.3.3, Python 2.7, MSSQL 2008 and 2012, and my ODBC.dll is 6.1.7601.17514 for both 64/32 bit

How to make it run on Python x64?

Comment: Have you tried pyodbc to see if it works better than pypyodbc on x64?

Comment: @Gord Thompson: I cannot use pyodbc, as I have certain requirements forbidding me to install binaries on the target machine. So even if it is working I cannot use it.

Comment: You might not be able to use it in production, but a successful *test* of pyodbc under 64-bit Python might point to a bug in pypyodbc. If that is the case then you'd either need tweak the pypyodbc code yourself, or reach out to someone who could do it for you.

Comment: ok, that sounds fine. I was not aware that both projects are coupled so tightly. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterParker Hi, Did you resolved this issue? Thanks.